# Sending click and keystrokes to a hidden panel in c#

Tags: c#, automation, panel

I Am working on a application that wraps a old java applet that runs in a browser.

Currently I am using AHK to automate certain tasks to good success but ive been thinking recently maybe a headless solution would be a better idea (As then new staff do not need to be trained on legacy software.)

I know how to display a application within a panel and i am thinking i could run the java applet within a hidden panel and then send input to this hidden panel..

is this at all possible?

I know how to hide a panel that has a embedded application, i know how to send virtual clicks and text input.

i want to combine these two things.